# how do i run multiple spark application on different worker nodes in standlone mode?

Tags: apache-spark

1.I have added these line ./conf/spark.env.sh

```
**export SPARK_MASTER_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=1"
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=1"
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=7**
```

2.i did run this code on terminal

**./sbin/start-all.sh**

3.all the workers and master are started..i can see that on web UI

4.after that i submitted multiple spark application

for one application it takes only 2s
but for 6 application ,each application takes 8sec

this is the .sh file i have run on terminal.

```
gnome-terminal -e '/home/uvionics/Downloads/spark-SparkR-streaming/bin/spark-submit --master spark://uvionics-Aspire-E5-001:7077 --executor-memory 1g  --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1 /home/uvionics/code/inter11.R 41' -x 'excute' &
 gnome-terminal -e '/home/uvionics/Downloads/spark-SparkR-streaming/bin/spark-submit --master spark://uvionics-Aspire-E5-001:7077 --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1 /home/uvionics/code/inter11.R 42' -x 'excute' & 
gnome-terminal -e '/home/uvionics/Downloads/spark-SparkR-streaming/bin/spark-submit --master spark://uvionics-Aspire-E5-001:7077 --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1 /home/uvionics/code/inter11.R 43' -x 'excute' & 
gnome-terminal -e '/home/uvionics/Downloads/spark-SparkR-streaming/bin/spark-submit --master spark://uvionics-Aspire-E5-001:7077 --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1  /home/uvionics/code/inter11.R 44' -x 'excute' & 
gnome-terminal -e '/home/uvionics/Downloads/spark-SparkR-streaming/bin/spark-submit --master spark://uvionics-Aspire-E5-001:7077  --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1 /home/uvionics/code/inter11.R 45 ' -x 'excute' &
gnome-terminal -e '/home/uvionics/Downloads/spark-SparkR-streaming/bin/spark-submit --master spark://uvionics-Aspire-E5-001:7077 --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1 /home/uvionics/code/inter11.R 46' -x 'excute'
```

when i did i run these code it takes more than 8sec

i think each application is running on master......
i want to run application parallely on each core of spark..
how do i run multiple spark application parallely??

Comment: May be the node where you are running spark submit (spark driver node) doesn't have enough resources to execute parallel . Can you check that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are running all the workers on one server to simulate a cluster.

The executor cores are different than normal cores.

The executor cores are the number of Concurrent tasks that an executor can run.
The worker cores - to make the workers run are the “CPU cores”.

In Spark there is the option to set the amount of CPU cores when starting a slave which defines the total CPU cores to allow Spark applications to use on the machine only on worker.
Default is: use all available cores

The command to start Spark would be something like this:
`./sbin/start-all.sh --cores 2`

Or you can try with `--executor-cores 2`

Comment: even though i wrote  the same and started all slaves, im getting the same result....